# Is "#\" used to comment next line in tcl?

Tags: bash, tcl

In below bash script, "exec expect " is invoked to replace the running bash process, so the whole script is processed again using tcl/expect.

I am wondering what line 2 "#\" is used for.

```
#!/bin/sh
#\
exec expect "$0" "$1"
puts "Hello!"
```

It seems to be used to comment the next line in tcl? Below is the output of this script named 1.

```
$ ./1
Hello!
```

Another question is why is $1 in the script necessary when no parameter is fed? If "$1" is removed from the "exec expect" line, the output would be

```
$ ./1
": no such file or directory
```

Comment: In both `shells` and `tcl` the character `#` is a comment. However, in shells, lines preceded by `#` is a comment and therefore the continuation line \ is treated as a comment. So line 2 is noting but a comment on shells. In `tcl`, the comment is still parsed and the line continuation \ is treated as such. So, in `tcl`, lines 2 and 3 is just a single comment. For your second question, it looks like your `expect` is a wrapper that requires a parameter. Check the file type of `expect` by running `file $(which expect)`.

Comment: Or you may have forgotten to remove the second parameter entirely, ending up with an empty second parameter such as `exec expect "$0" ""`.

Comment: @alvits, so you mean the comment line in tcl starting with # is still parsed by tcl? Then it's not a real comment, is it?

Comment: It is a "real" comment, it's simply a question of at what stage in the input processing does the comment get ignored? In Tcl, the input processing step that decides what one "line" is happens _before_ the step where comments are discarded. And the rules for "line" say that backslash-newline is a line continuation.

Answer (score 2):

I think normally the idiom is `exec expect "$0" "${1+$@}"` which is a fancy way of saying "if there is a first argument, give all the arguments. That was invented for old shells. use `exec expect "$0" "$@"`, or more simply

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
```

Answer (score 2):

> It seems to be used to comment the next line in tcl?

Yes. Tcl's backslash-newline-whitespace handling interacts with comments, and one of the consequences is that you can use `#\` to make the next line a comment. It's a bit of an edge-case in practice.

> Another question is why is `$1` in the script necessary when no parameter is fed?

It is not necessary. The old preferred way of doing it would be `${1+"$@"}`, and on any modern shell it's actually just `"$@"` (the `${1+…}` was to work around a bug in one relatively common commercial Unix). This is all a bit magical, but expands to the list of arguments as quoted values, so that passing spaces (etc) via the arguments can work.

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec expect "$0" "$@"
```

Of course, delegating to `/usr/bin/env` is better:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
```

as that's *much* simpler and involves no hacks or trickery at all.